# How to get Sku, name, and image in magento2 through programmatically?

Tags: product, admin, product-attribute, magento-2.2.5

I don't know how to implement this task. I want to get product name, SKU, and image in magento2. Can you please help me?

Comment: where  you want to get those data?

Comment: Hi @ Amit Bera, I have created one php file in the magento2 root folder. This is my required file path localhost/magento2test/example.php

Answer (score 5):

I think you can fetch all product data using following code. Just put this code in your php file `example.php`. Hope it works.

```
 <?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params =  $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaurl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
     echo 'Sku  =  '.$product->getSku().'<br><br>';
     $imagepath = $mediaurl.'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();
     $img = '<img src='.$imagepath.' />';
     echo $img;
}  

?>
```

Comment: Hi @ Raj, I want to get and display image also along with name and SKU.

Comment: @DileepKumar Have you tried $product->getImage(); or $product->getMediaGalleryImages() for displaying image?

Comment: Hi @ Raj, it is displaying URL path but I want to display the image?

Comment: @DileepKumar Then you can add that url path in <img src="image_url"/> tag.

Comment: Hi @ Raj , I have added this code <img src="<?php $product->getImage(); ?>"> but image not displaying

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check.

Comment: Hi @ Raj, thanks. The image is displaying.

Comment: The image are showing now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

try
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product_Id = 5;
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_Id);

    //product name 
    echo $product->getName();

    //product Sku
    echo $product->getSku();

    //Product Image
    if($product->getImage() != '')
    {
        echo $product->getImage();
    }
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SKU**:

```
<?php $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>
```

**Product Name**:

```
<?php
      $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
?>
```

**Image**:

```
<?php 
     $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); 
     $img = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                    ->init($product, 'product_base_image')
                    ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                    ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                    ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
                    ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                    ->resize(320, 240);
?>
```

Use below line wherever you want your image to be displayed:

```
<?php echo $img->getUrl(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put below code in your file example.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$store = $obj->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

/** get product data by product id ****/
$productId = 1;
$product = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')
               ->getById($productId);

echo "Name :".$product->getName();
echo "Sku :". $product->getSku();
echo "Image : ".$store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage to work this by using following code:

```
<?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $params = $_SERVER;
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();

    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

    foreach ($collection as $product){
        $name = $product->getName();
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        $imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();
        $image = '<img src="'.$imageUrl.'"/>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Sukumar Gorai, I need your help. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php  
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('./app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
 
$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
getAllProducts($objectManager);

function getAllProducts($objectManager) {

$header[]=array('sku');
    $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    $app_state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($collection as $product){
            $id=$product->getId();
            $sku=$product->getSku();
            $header[]=array($sku);
            echo $counter++.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $fp = fopen("sku.csv","w"); 
    foreach ($header as $line) {
        fputcsv($fp, $line);
    }
    fclose($fp);      
}
?>
```